# Finite ring extension and field of fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra

There is a proposition:

Let $A$ be a Noetherian integral domain, $B$ be an integral domain and $A \subset B$ a finite extension.

Then
$A\subset B\cap Q(A)$ is also a finite extension where $Q(A)$ is field of fractions of $A$.

The proof is easy.
Since $B$ is f.g $A$-module and $A$ is a Noetherian ring, $B$ is a Noetherian $A$-module.
Hence $B\cap Q(A)$, which is submodule of $B$ is also finite.

Do you have any counterexample where $A$ is not Noetherian?

Comment: The claim is trivial, as the intersection is contained in $B$. Is that what you really want to ask? PS: I also fixed the grammar and the LaTeX, please consider doing this next time.

Comment: I was wrong. I corrected my question.